# Using linebreak to break IF statement in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, line-breaks

I have a VBA conditional script as below:

```
If COMORBIDITY_CANCER = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_CHRONIC_SKIN_LESIONS = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_CHRONIC_LUNG_DISEASE = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_CARDIOVASCULAR_DISEASE = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_DM = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_IMMUNODEFICIENCY_OR_CHEMOTHERAPY = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_ADL = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_HEPATIC_DISEASE = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_RENAL_IMPAIRMENT = -1 Then
RS_REPORT.AddNew
RS_REPORT!REPORT_UID = REPORT_UID
RS_REPORT!CATEGORY1_ID = 2
RS_REPORT!CATEGORY2_ID = 1
RS_REPORT!CATEGORY3_ID = 1
RS_REPORT.Update
End If
```

I think the first line of it is too long and I would like to chop it using ENTER, like what can be done in R, but seems it is invalid in VBA, I tried

```
& _
```

but it also fails.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the underscore without the ampersand?

Comment: +1 @Jay. The ampersand is a string concatenation operator and you're not concatenating strings, just the underscore should do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
If COMORBIDITY_CANCER = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_CHRONIC_SKIN_LESIONS = -1 Or _
COMORBIDITY_CHRONIC_LUNG_DISEASE = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_CARDIOVASCULAR_DISEASE = -1 Or _
COMORBIDITY_DM = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_IMMUNODEFICIENCY_OR_CHEMOTHERAPY = -1 Or _
COMORBIDITY_ADL = -1 Or COMORBIDITY_HEPATIC_DISEASE = -1 Or _
COMORBIDITY_RENAL_IMPAIRMENT = -1 Then
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something such as:

```
Boolean b = false
If condition1 b = true
If condition2 b = true
 . . .
If b ...
```